# Create a group that doesnt depend on a Snap instance

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Here is what I want to do :

```
var a = Snap("#id");

var group = new SnapGroup(); // unfortunatly didnt find how to do it
// for some reasons i dont want to do a.group();
group.circle(5,5,5);
a.add(group);
```

Here is what I did :

```
var a = Snap("#id");

s = Snap(); // creates a SVG element instead of a group
s.circle(5,5,5);

a.add(s);
```

It works, the circle is rendered, but then I cannot move the group :

```
s.attr({"x":60}); // the group doesnt move
```

Actually it looks like that when we embed and `<svg>` elements into an other one. Then it becomes impossible to move the embeded svg element in the parent one.

I would like to know how to create a group element without doing `snapInstance.group()` ? And then add it to a Snap instance.

Comment: Can you explain why you specifically don't want to use snapinstance.group() ? Normally I would create the group and circle and add it, and then perform a translate transform on the group, but you are removing the obvious possibility for some reason without explaining why (so we can't come up with a workaround).

Comment: Because i'm generating the group in an object that has no dependancy with the Snap instance. Then i want this object to be able to create a group and to share it (clones) with many Snap instances. But it looks  like i will have to refactor this object to draw the group on the snap instance from oine of its methods instead of getting the group and adding it to snapinstance after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure from your description what you are after, as I suspect it may depend how you are generating the original group (if its just a bit of svg markup or imported).

```
 Snap.parse('<g></g>'); may be enough to fiddle with, to parse into a fragment.
```

See if this helps...its an example with two separate SVG elements and Snap instances. It will draw a rect from the original SVG markup string with a group,add a circle from Snap, and on the 2nd instance it will translate the group by 75 as well.

```
<svg id="svg1" width="200" height="200"></svg><br />
<svg id="svg2" width="200" height="200"></svg>

...
    var paper1 = Snap("#svg1");
    var paper2 = Snap("#svg2");
    var groupMarkup = '<g><rect x="0" y="0" width="70" height="70" opacity="0.3"/><text x="0" y="15">original</text></g>'; 

    var parsedMarkup1 = Snap.parse( groupMarkup ); //parse from a string derived elsewhere
    var parsedMarkup2 = Snap.parse( groupMarkup );


    // example1  just use the markup with its original group

    paper1.add( parsedMarkup1 )
          .add( paper1.circle(100,50,50)
                      .attr('fill', 'red' ) );


    // example2, will create a new group and add the existing group to it, and then move it

    var outerG = paper2.g()
                       .transform('t75,0');    //create a group and move it
    outerG.add( parsedMarkup2 );               //add the original group/square
    outerG.add( paper2.circle(70,50,50)        //add a circle
                      .attr('fill', 'blue' ) );

   var clone = outerG.clone();                  //lets create a clone
    clone.transform('r45t50,50');               //translate and rotate the clone
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/v4bJa/

Comment: That's mostly what i was looking for ! I would have loved to have an object that i can extend, instanciate, and so on, but that's enough to solve my problem. Thanks